# ¿Cómo escribir por pantalla en cuáles posiciones de la Matriz se encuentran las letras asociadas a mi nombre que están almacenadas en el Vector?

Tags: c++, array, matrices, dev-c++, vectores

Si pueden ayudar se los agradecería muchísimo, soy nuevo en esto de la programación y me cuesta un poco. Bueno les explico, este ejercicio consiste en realizar un ejercicio en c++ que almacene en un Vector las letras que contiene mi primer nombre (lo cual ya lo hice)

Almacenar en una Matriz las letras del Abecedario (ya también lo hice y lo tengo listo).

Muestre en la pantalla el Vector y la Matriz.(al igual que mostrar la matriz ya lo realice).

Pero cuando llego a esta parte nose como realizar esto:

Escriba en la pantalla en cuáles posiciones de la Matriz se encuentran las letras asociadas a tu
nombre que están almacenadas en el Vector.

llevo aproximadamente 2 días tratando de buscar info de algún ejercicio parecido pero no he conseguido nada que me haya dejado algo claro, y aun no he podido terminar el ejercicio

Esto es lo que llevo de código...

#include 
using namespace std;

char nombre [6] = {'J','O','R','G','E','\0'};
char abc [5][6] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','\0'};
int f,c;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

```
cout<<"I D E N T I F I C A C I O N"<<endl;
cout<<"Nombre: Jorge Ramirez"<<endl;
cout<<"C.I: 29.555.990"<<endl;

cout<<"VECTOR CON MI NOMBRE:"<<endl;
cout<<nombre;

cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;

for (f=0;f<5;f++)
    
{
    cout<<f+1;
    
    for (c=0;c<6;c++)
    {
        cout<<"\t\t"<<abc[f][c];
        
    }
    
    cout<<endl;
}

cout<<endl<<endl;

cout<<"NOMBRE:"; cout<<"\t\t"; cout<<"POSICIONES:";

cout<<endl<<endl;

cout<<"J:";

return 0;
```

}

tiene que quedar parecido a esto mas o menos:

[image]

Comment: Hola Jorge, podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron útiles y si son correctas darles un voto y marcar como aceptada la que haya resuelto el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas veces no vamos encontrar exactamente lo que buscamos en internet, ya tienes avanzando la mayor parte de tu ejercicio entonces debes plantearte ¿Cómo puedo encontrar cada letra de mi nombre en la matriz?, si es posible agarras una hoja de papel y comienzas a describir los pasos que necesitas realizar.

1. Agarro la primera letra de mi nombre y lo busco en la matriz.
2. Encuentro la letra en la matriz, entonces ubico en que fila y columna en el cual se encuentra.
3. Repito el mismo paso hasta terminar todas las letras de mi nombre.

Entonces una vez tengo claro los pasos a seguir comienzo a codificar, para ello necesitarías 2 `vectores` para guardar la `posición` de cada `fila` y `columna` donde he encontrado la letra en la matriz.

Para mostrar la salida de que quieres, sólo tienes que recorrer el vector de tu nombre y escribir los vectores de fila y columna que has encontrado.
Te dejo el código completo.

```
using namespace std;

char nombre [6] = {'J','O','R','G','E'}; 
char abc [5][6] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','\0'}; 
int f,c,filas[6],columnas[6];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

cout<<"I D E N T I F I C A C I O N"<<endl;
cout<<"Nombre: Jorge Ramirez"<<endl;
cout<<"C.I: 29.555.990"<<endl;

cout<<"VECTOR CON MI NOMBRE:"<<endl;
cout<<nombre;

cout<<endl;
cout<<endl; 
        
        for (f=0;f<5;f++)           
        {
            cout<<f+1;
            
            for (c=0;c<6;c++)
            {
                cout<<"\t\t"<<abc[f][c];                            
            }           
            cout<<endl;
        }
    
    //Encontramos la posición de cada letra del nombre
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){       
        for (f=0;f<5;f++)       
        {                   
            for (c=0;c<6;c++)
            {               
                if(nombre[i]==abc[f][c]) {
                    filas[i]=f;
                    columnas[i]=c;
                }               
            }               
        }
    }

cout<<endl<<endl;

cout<<"NOMBRE:"; cout<<"\t\t"; cout<<"POSICIONES:";

cout<<endl<<endl;
    
    //Mostramos la salida deseada
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<nombre[i]<<":"<<"\t\t["<<filas[i]+1<<","<<columnas[i]+1<<"]"<<endl;
    
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gras mi bro, ya comprendí el ejercicio, de verdad que te agradezco, saludos!!!

Comment: @JorgeMiguel de nada bro éxitos, si mi respuesta y/o la otra respuesta te fue de ayuda marcar ``Esta respuesta ha sido útil`` en la flecha que está al costado de tu pregunta, también puedes dar clic en el icono del ``check`` que esta debajo de las 2 flechas al costado de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

```
int cont = sizeof(nombre)/sizeof(nombre[0]);
bool stop = false;

for(int i = 0; i < cont; i++)
{ 
   stop = false;

   for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
   {
      if(stop)
      {
         break;
      }

      for(int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
      {
         if(nombre[i] == abc[j, k];
         {
            cout << nombre[i] << ":  " << "[" << j << "," << k << "]";
            stop = true;
            break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Se hacen tres **ciclos for anidados**, el primero para recorrer cada caracter del arreglo del nombre y los 2 interiores para recorrer la matriz del alfabeto.

Si encontramos que alguna letra del nombre coincide con alguna letra del alfabeto imprimimimos la letra del nombre y su respectiva posición en la matriz.

La **variable cont** va a guardar la longitud del arreglo, en **C++**, la longitud de un arreglo se calcula usando el **operador sizeof**, investiga más sobre el en internet.

La **variable stop** nos sirve para evitar iteraciones de más, ya que si encontramos que la letra del nombre coincide con alguna letra del alfabeto, hacemos la impresión antes mencionada y salimos del tercer ciclo usando break, y entonces caeríamos en el segundo ciclo, preguntaríamos si stop es true y saldríamos de este segundo ciclo, y volvería a empezar todo el proceso con la próxima letra del arreglo de nombre.

Answer (score 0):

cout<<"Nombre: Jorge Ramirez"<<endl;
cout<<"C.I: 29.555.990"<<endl;

cout<<"VECTOR CON MI NOMBRE:"<<endl;
cout<<nombre;

cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).